# How to program an nRF52 DK to send BLE MIDI message when I push a button?

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, midi, nrf52

I'm new developing using real C language. I have more experience using Arduino.
I'm trying to send a MIDI message over Bluetooth MIDI when I push one of the buttons of my Nordic nRF52 DK. But I'm not being successful. How can I do that?

I tried to use this tutorial: https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-gatt-services-characteristics/
Everything works fine and I'm able to create a discoverable BLE MIDI device. But I'm stuck setting a way to send actual MIDI messages.
I've made a test simply using the buttons to turn on/off the DK LEDs and here it's everything fine

I suppose that I should somehow configure something here (midi_service.c):

```
**@brief Function for handling the Write event.
 *
 * @param[in]   p_midi_service   LED Button Service structure.
 * @param[in]   p_ble_evt        Event received from the BLE stack.
 */
static void on_write(ble_midi_service_t * p_midi_service, ble_evt_t const * p_ble_evt)
{
    ble_gatts_evt_write_t * p_evt_write = (ble_gatts_evt_write_t *) &p_ble_evt->evt.gatts_evt.params.write;

    if ((p_evt_write->handle == p_midi_service->data_io_char_handles.value_handle) &&
        (p_evt_write->len == 1) &&
        (p_midi_service->evt_handler != NULL))
    {
      // Handle what happens on a write event to the characteristic value
    }

    // Check if the Custom value CCCD is written to and that the value is the appropriate length, i.e 2 bytes.
    if ((p_evt_write->handle == p_midi_service->data_io_char_handles.cccd_handle)
        && (p_evt_write->len == 2)
       )
    {
        // CCCD written, call application event handler
        if (p_midi_service->evt_handler != NULL)
        {
            ble_midi_evt_t evt;

            if (ble_srv_is_notification_enabled(p_evt_write->data))
            {
                evt.evt_type = BLE_DATA_IO_EVT_NOTIFICATION_ENABLED;
            }
            else
            {
                evt.evt_type = BLE_DATA_IO_EVT_NOTIFICATION_DISABLED;
            }

            p_midi_service->evt_handler(p_midi_service, &evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Then find a way to call it on my main code here:

```
case BSP_EVENT_KEY_3:
             LEDS_ON(1 << LED_4);
             //MIDI message

case BSP_EVENT_KEY_2:
             LEDS_OFF(1 << LED_4);
             //MIDI message
```

If I try for example:

```
case BSP_EVENT_KEY_3:
             LEDS_ON(1 << LED_4);
             ble_add_char_params_t (0x80, 0x80, 0x90, 0x3c, 127);
```

(The idea here is to send a Note On message)
I get the error "expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant" while compiling.
Probably this is a really silly approach, but as I said, I'm a newbie on this type of coding, so not really sure how to do it.
Using Arduino I'm able to do it, but I want to learn how to code it more "seriously".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove html-encoded characters (`&gt;` in lieu of `<`, etc.).

Comment: As your code doesn't compile, please add the full error message and the source code refered to in the error message and mark the source code line the error message refers to.

Comment: And what is `ble_add_char_params_t` ? A typename?

Comment: Sorry. Right now got a bit lost on it. As I said I'm really starting out :/ I tried this already some days ago and to be honest can't find now from where I toke it.
I know (from my experience coding this with Arduino) that to send a MIDI message you should pack that message with the BLE Characteristics.
Something like this on Arduino:

Comment: BLECharacteristic   midiCharacteristic ("7772E5DB-3868-4112-A1A9-F2669D106BF3", BLEWrite | BLEWriteWithoutResponse | BLERead | BLENotify, 5);
//Buffer to hold 5 bytes of MIDI data. Note the timestamp is forced
uint8_t midiData[] = {0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

Comment: //Loads up buffer with Continuous Controller messages
void sendCC(char chan, char controller, int val) {
  midiData[2] = 0xB0 + chan;
  midiData[3] = controller;
  midiData[4] = val;
  midiCharacteristic.setValue(midiData, 5);//midiData); //posts 5 bytes
}